# Cannot access wsdlURL - using Netbeans 7.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

first post here, I am creating a webservice client on Netbeans 7.0, followed all the steps and got the generated code (java-ws), I built the project (.WAR) on Windows and copied it to my testing server (JBOSS on Unix), when I run the client (Through my web browser) it generates the following error:

2011-05-25 13:20:31,272 WARN  [org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegateImpl] Cannot access wsdlURL: file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/FRGHOSN/Desktop/pp.wsdl
2011-05-25 13:20:31,276 WARN  [org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegateImpl] Cannot get port meta data for: {http://77.246.32.166/}CuWebServiceSoap

Now I checked for solutions and someone suggested changing the generated WebService class

here is the part I was supposed to change:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "CuWebService", targetNamespace = "http://xxx", wsdlLocation = "file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/FRGHOSN/Desktop/pp.wsdl")
public class CuWebService
    extends Service
{

    private final static URL CUWEBSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException CUWEBSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName CUWEBSERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://xxx/", "CuWebService");

    static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/FRGHOSN/Desktop/pp.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        CUWEBSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        CUWEBSERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
    }
```

I edited the URL to `url= client.CuWebservice.class.getResource("/WEB-INF/wsdl/pp.wsdl")`

and it's not working

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance